# IP Routing through VPN to Windows Server

Tags: windows-7, route

I have the following network topology:

- Remote admin network (192.168.10.0/24) I connect to using PPTP to the public IP
- Remote gateway assigns an IP adress to me (192.168.10.100, for instance)
- I can reach any server on the 192.168.10.0/24 subnet
- I cannot reach any server on the 192.168.20.0/24 (DMZ) subnet
- Note that I added a static route in Windows in order to route the traffic to 192.168.20.0/24 through the VPN's gateway (192.168.100.1):

> Persistent Routes:
> Network Address     Netmask           Gateway Address  Metric
> 192.168.20.0        255.255.255.0     192.168.10.1       1

(sorry for poor formating)

However when I do a trace route, I can clearly see that Windows is routing the packets to my default, non VPN, gateway:

> Tracing route to 192.168.20.1 over a maximum of 30 hops
>
> 1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  my.firewall [192.168.2.1]
> 2     5 ms     4 ms     4 ms  192.168.1.1
> 3  (edited out public ip) reports: Destination net unreachable.

How can this be? Why is Windows routing to my default gateway (192.168.2.1) when I explicitely specified a different gateway for this destination subnet (192.168.20.0) ?

Comment: could you provide the complete output of route print, ipconfig /all and which windows version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question but here goes.

Basically I simply had to re-add the route manually (route add 192.168.20.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1). Doing this fixed the issue. Apparently, even though the route shows as "Persistent" it was not. This happens whenever I reboot. I don't know if it's a bug or simply because interface numbers can change between two reboots (both sound very doubtful but that's all I can think of).

Answer (score 0):

Without further info I would guess you need to provide the interface number when adding the route. For example if the vpn if is number 18 then

route -p add 192.168.20.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1 if 18

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Serves me right for writing this on my phone w/o access to a computer.

The route you're manually adding should reference the IP assigned to the local machine's PPTP interface, not the default gateway on the remote network. It's counter-intuitive, but it'll work. For a long-term solution you can use a [DHCP option](http://serverfault.com/questions/261236/windows-server-2008-r2-rras-vpn-client-routing/261259#261259) to push out the route.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the remote server's PPTP interface *is* the default gateway on the remote network.

Comment: @Furism: I dropped on an edit because my recollection was poor.