# How to set up routing for RRAS VPN connections

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, routing

I have a NAT/firewall running DHCP for the LAN configured to forward the VPN ports directly to the Windows 2008R2 server behind the firewall on NIC1. The LAN switch is also connected to the firewall for internet access.

RRAS/VPN is setup on the Windows server which is also the DC and local DNS server at this point. NIC2 on the server connects to the LAN switch and connectivity to the internet and LAN works fine for the local subnet (192.168.1.0).

VPN clients can connect but then they cannot connect to any office network or internet addresses nor can they resolve DNS unless the "use default gateway on remote network" option is turned off, then the internet is available to them.

This looks like a routing table issue but I don't know how to set that up properly. Any ideas?

IPCONFIG /ALL

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : LDMSERV2
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : LDM.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : LDM.local

PPP adapter RAS (Dial In) Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : RAS (Dial In) Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.107(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VPN HOST:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom BCM5716C NetXtreme II
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 78-2B-CB-33-A7-99
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom BCM5716C NetXtreme II
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 78-2B-CB-33-A7-98
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.8(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.8
                                       127.0.0.1
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: I think you're confusing some terms here, what is the `intranet (192.18.1.0)`?  That sounds like your local subnet, not an intranet (which typically refers to an outside network or 'network between networks').

Comment: Yes, I've rephrased this question to be more specific

Comment: Have you tried enabling the LAN Routing option on the RRAS server?

Comment: So, you have NIC1 on the server connected directly to the firewall (via an internal switch or a DMZ port?), and then also connected to your LAN [switch] as well?  So presumably you have two IP addresses, one for each NIC.  Could you post the configuration of those two NICs (ie. IP/subnet mask/default gateway)?

Comment: see the edited post for my NIC configuration from ipconfig /all

Comment: @joequerty - Is that the option under Routing and Remote Access > Properties > Enable this computer as a: IPv4 Router ?  This is selected and LAN routing only is selected.

Comment: @stinkbutt (stinkbutt... really?) - yes, that's what I was referring to.

Comment: didn't help.  :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did to get it to work.

1. Configured *Remote Access Logging and Policies* (Right-click > *Launch NPS*)
2. Added a policy to allow my remote access users to access the network (this alone did not remedy the situation and may not have been the issue but I did it anyway)
3. Under *Routing and Remote Access Properties* > *IPv4* tab, switched to *Static address pool*
4. Set up an address space that was unused by the NAT/DHCP server for the RRAS DHCP pool (192.168.1.201-250)
5. Selected *Enable broadcast name resolution* and used NIC2 (the LAN subnet) as the Adapter for DHCP/DNS/WINS

Everything resolved after that!  Thank you everyone for your help and for the other ServerFault articles that pointed me in the right direction.